# array merge using column value in given array example

Tags: php

I want to add both array column using year 
first array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2016
        [voucher] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2017
        [voucher] => 9
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2018
        [voucher] => 6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2015
        [voucher] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2014
        [voucher] => 2
    )
```

)

second array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2018
        [sample] => 4
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2017
        [sample] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2016
        [sample] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2015
        [sample] => 1
    )
```

)``

enter code here`

output look like as given below.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2016
        [voucher] => 7
        [sample] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2017
        [voucher] => 9
        [sample] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2018
        [voucher] => 6
        [sample] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2015
        [voucher] => 1
        [sample] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2014
        [voucher] => 2
    )
```

)

Comment: Well, if that's what you want to do, you should probably write some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

```
$arA = array( '0' => array( 'year' => '2016', 'voucher' => '7' ),
              '1' => array( 'year' => '2017', 'voucher' => '9' ),
              '2' => array( 'year' => '2018', 'voucher' => '6' ),
              '3' => array( 'year' => '2015', 'voucher' => '1' ),
              '4' => array( 'year' => '2014', 'voucher' => '2' )

          );


$arB = array( '0' => array( 'year' => '2018', 'sample' => '4' ),
              '1' => array( 'year' => '2017', 'sample' => '3' ),
              '2' => array( 'year' => '2016', 'sample' => '2' ),
              '3' => array( 'year' => '2015', 'sample' => '1' )

          );


$newArr = array_merge( $arA, $arB );

$output = array();

foreach( $newArr as $v ) {

    if( !isset( $output[ $v[ "year" ] ] ) ) {

        $output[ $v[ "year" ] ] = $v;

    }else {

        $output[ $v[ "year" ] ][ "sample" ] = $v[ "sample" ];

    }

}

$output = array_values( $output );

print_r( $output );
```

Let me know if you find a better solution.